# VBA Excel Sum column and rows

Tags: sql, vba, excel

```
    ABC ASD BHP WER THY SUM    
1   789 564 654 546 654 3207

2   103 123 213 123 654 1216    
3   546 394 879 654 654 2733
```

My question is how can I sum each column and row? If there is a gap row? I am trying to process each row so that it sums.  It works if there is no gap in the data, but if there is a gap between the rows it doesn't fully process each cell.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub test()

Dim intRowTot As Integer
Dim intRowCnt As Integer
Dim intColTot As Integer
Dim intColCnt As Integer

Range("B2").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    intRowTot = 0
    intColTot = 0

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        intRowTot = intRowTot + 1
        intColTot = intColTot + ActiveCell.Value
        intColCnt = intColCnt + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = intColTot
    ActiveCell.Offset(-intRowTot, 1).Select
    Loop

Range("B2").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    intRowTot = 0
    intColTot = 0

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        intRowTot = intRowTot + ActiveCell.Value
        intColTot = intColTot + 1
        intRowCnt = intRowCnt + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = intRowTot
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -intColTot).Select
    Loop
End Sub`
```

Comment: Any reason why you need VBA for this rather than to display the sums on the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is almost 100% not to be using VBA for this but rather to be using spreadsheet formulas:

```
=SUM(B2:B4)
```

etc.

If you 100% need to be using VBA for this for some reason, spreadsheet formulas are still likely the right answer:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B2:B4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ABC ASD BHP WER THY    
789 564 654 546 654

103 123 213 123 654   
546 394 879 654 654
```

Table above, code below:

```
Sub test()


Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim tempsum As Long
'columns
For i = 1 To 5
    tempsum = 0
    For j = 1 To 5
        If IsNumeric(Cells(j, i).Value) = True Then
            tempsum = tempsum + Cells(j, i).Value
        End If
    Next
    If tempsum > 0 Then
        Cells(j, i).Value = tempsum
    End If
Next


'rows
For i = 1 To 5
    tempsum = 0
    For j = 1 To 5
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, j).Value) = True Then
            tempsum = tempsum + Cells(i, j).Value
        End If
    Next
    If tempsum > 0 Then
        Cells(i, j).Value = tempsum
    End If
Next



End Sub
```